# Android - Navigation View item menu background color

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, navigationview

i try to change color of my item Navigation View menu :

styles.xml

```
<item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/activated_background</item>
```

activated_background.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/White" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/White" />
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/White" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

drawer.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group
    android:id="@+id/group_1">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/drawer_menu_account"
        android:checked="false"
        android:title="@string/menu_account"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_account_grey600_24dp" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/drawer_menu_my_post"
        android:checked="false"
        android:title="@string/menu_my_post"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_pin_grey600_24dp" />
</group>
[...]
```

**Background color don't change.. 
What am i doing wrong ?**

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You don't set the drawable for the background of a Navigation View item in your styles.xml file. Open up your XML layout file containing your Navigation View widget, and add the following line to the widget's attributes:

```
app:itemBackground="@drawable/activated_background.xml"
```

If you're having trouble with the "app" pointer, add the following line in as well:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Note that this only changes the colour of the background of a selected list item. If you'd like the icon and text colour to change as well, use the `app:itemTextColor` attribute instead.

Comment: Thanks, It's work. So the line in styles.xml can be remove.

Comment: this works find but for checked state is not working for selector

Comment: Nice solution. Is there any way to keep the background in a selected state?

Comment: @HaloMediaz have you already solved to keep the background when selected after the drawer is closed?

Comment: make sure each of the menuItems have explicitly set "isCheckable" to true.

Answer (score 19):

Below code works fine for me
my nav view:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/nav.background"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_item_background"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_item_text"/>
```

drawable/nav_item_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/nav.item.background" />
  <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/nav.item.background" />
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/nav.item.background" />
  <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/nav.item.background" />
  <item android:drawable="@color/nav.item.background.default" />
</selector>
```

drawable/nav_item_text.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="@android:color/white" android:state_checked="true" />
  <item android:color="#bdbdbd" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed solution.

Comment: It changes background color of Parent Menu item but what about child?

Answer (score 5):

You must use android:background="color" for back color of navigation menu
like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/shitstuff"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
        app:menu="@menu/drawermenu"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_marginTop="-24dp"
        />
```

and for items color use itemTextColor="color"

Comment: Thanks, and, howto change the separator group line color from the properties?

Answer (score 4):

To have the background display on your selected item you need to add

```
 android:checkable="true"
```

on every item of your menu.xml items, then set :

```
app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_view_item_background"
```

on your NavigationView and finally: 
 
drawable/nav_view_item_background.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/primary" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Comment: My pleasure, say hello to your cat for me :)

Answer (score 3):

@HaloMediaz and @HemantShori
To keep the background of the selected item in a selected state,

use `android:state_checked="true"` instead of `android:state_pressed="true"` in the color state resource.

So your activated color state resource should look like this:

activated_background.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/White" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/White" />
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/White" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Comment: your answer was correct for me, but look on code when you copy it, you didnt change state_pressed to state_checked

Comment: I just saw that. That was an oversight on my part. I've corrected it.