# setting background and text color to topmost item in hamburger android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, menuitem

I want to set a black background with a white textview to the topmost item of the hamburger menu.It tried dynamically but setting Menu Item class does not have any propert setBackgroundDrawable etc.This is my menu and I want to set the background to navigation_item_1.pls help me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<group android:id="@+id/grp1" android:checkableBehavior="single" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_1"
        android:checked="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:title="get i5 Pro" />
</group>

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
<item
android:id="@+id/home"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
android:title="Home"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/activate_pro"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_pro"
    android:title="Active PRO"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/my_music"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_music_list"
    android:title="My Music"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_browse"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_brows_black"
        android:title="Browse and Discover" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/radio_stations"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_radio_station"
        android:title="Radio Stations"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/new_releases"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_new_release"
    android:title="New Releases"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/my_profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"
        android:title="My Profile" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/music_lang"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_checked"
        android:title="Music Languages" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
        android:title="Settings"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_login"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_logout"
        android:title="Log in " />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_log_out"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_logout"
        android:title="Log out " />
</group>
</menu>
```

Comment: You want to set to only first item of the menu? Are you using navigation drawer in only one activity?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31336169/5094531

Comment: @R.R.M yes i want the first item to have a black background with a white textview.the rest are fine as they are.I am using navigation drawer in main activity and clicking on a menu item replaces fragments accordingly

Comment: @AyushBansal wont that add background to the whole drawer ayush?I wnat it just for the top item

Comment: Ok fine i m posting the code.

Comment: Before posting i wanted to confirm is the first item is selected item of your menu in your drawer activity class?

Comment: @R.R.Mthe first item by default will be with black background and white textview like we have in saavn app.On selecting it will open the fragment

Comment: @R.R.M any news for me?

Comment: I have posted code. Please check it and don't forget to read second last line. It is very important.

Answer (score 0):

In xml file having navigation view add following code inside navigation view as :

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="330dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp" 
            android:src="@drawable/ic_home"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mSwitch"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="get i5 Pro" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Where you have to give margin top of linear layout according to your header height.. e.g. If your header height is 320 dp then you need to increase is by 10 dp or more according to your requirement.

Comment: R.R.M thanks.but it partially works because by default now I get the top item with black background but if I select any other option that icon has that black background while the top item again gets a white background which I dont want.for the rest of the icon clicking on an option will have the default grey background while the top item background should always be black whether selected or unselected.if u check saavn once u will be able to understand.I just want exactly like that.pls help me

Comment: Ok i m editing my code... Undo the previous changes.. I m changing code.